# Reducing size of Sage after building from source

Tags: disk-usage, sagemath

I built the maths software [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) from source onto my Ubuntu server. It now takes up 4.1GB of space in my `/opt`.

I am near the limit of my partition size and was wondering if anyone knew what I can remove to free up space without breaking the program.

Note, the first level of the sage directory tree is:

```
bin    c_lib  ext               fpickle_setup.pyc  Makefile     module_list.py   sage
build  doc    fpickle_setup.py  mac-app            MANIFEST.in  module_list.pyc  setup.py
```

Comment: you just want to compress sage or want to free your drive space?

Comment: Free the drive space, so delete anything that is unnecessary to running it.

Comment: I think you should try bleachbit

Comment: Its more I want to know what in the sage directory I can delete that won't break it i.e. the uncompiled source code.

Comment: I don't know that I just told you how to clear up system space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/source.html#make-targets

```
make distclean
```

... ever heard of RTFM? ;-)